# How does Plink parse session names?

Tags: putty, plink

If Plink is invoked with an argument which could be a host name or a saved PuTTY session, how is it parsed?

For example, suppose I have saved a PuTTY session named "192.168.4.4".  Will the following invoke the saved session?
`plink user1@192.168.4.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer:  In that example, Plink will use the PuTTY session.  The session configuration will add to, and possibly override, the Plink arguments.
Recommendation:  Avoid PuTTY session names which might be confused with a hostname.

---

Here's a more detailed explanation.  I inferred these Plink parsing rules from testing.

1. If the `-load` option is used, then load that saved session, do not look for a hostname in the argument list, and skip to step 5.
2. HOST=host name argument (from the argument list).
3. If HOST contains `@`, then split it at the last `@`.  USER=the first part, HOST=the last part.
4. If HOST matches the name of a saved PuTTY session, then load the parameters from that session.  If the session has a username, override the current value in USER.
5. Parse remaining arguments, overriding current values.  This includes `-l` for user, and `-i` for ssh user key.

---

Here is an example of how a saved session could cause problems.  Suppose this is a saved PuTTY session:

- name of saved session:  192.168.4.4
- host:  user2@192.168.5.5
- private key:  key.ppk

If you invoke Plink with `plink user1@192.168.4.4`, it will actually use the following:

- host: 192.168.**5.5** (from the saved session)
- user:  user**2** (the saved session value, user2, overrides user**1** in the argument)
- private key:  key.ppk (from the saved session)

---

Note 1:  This is the order of precedence for the username:  (1) `-l` option, (2) saved session, (3) attached to host argument with `@`.

Note 2:  PuTTY saves its sessions here in the windows registry.
(Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions)

Note 3:  Plink also allows you to invoke a saved session with the `-load` option, or `@session` (deprecated). These are described in [PuTTY documentation](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.78/htmldoc/).

Note 4:  I am using PuTTY release 0.71, 64-bit x86 Windows.  The latest version is 0.78.

Note 5:  Using a key from a saved session worked for me, but someone else reported problems with that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689583/putty-connects-but-key-refused-when-using-plink